# xmpp:xep-0077 for iOS gives me errors

Tags: ios, xmpp, registration

I found in the link below the xep-0077 and I added it in my xmpp-iOS project.

https://github.com/buddycloud/buddycloud-iOS-client/tree/master/src/External_Libs/XMPP/Extensions/XEP-0077

Unfortunately I get many errors.

I use the xmpp framework by robbiehanson (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) and what I am trying to do is to register a new user within my chat app.

Do I have to use the xep-0077 (band-in registration), or are there any other ways to register?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: That depends on which server you're connecting to. Some servers allow in-band registration, but many don't.

Comment: I use the ejabberd server